# Node js exporting Module return an undefined value in another file where I import it

Tags: node.js

I am getting undefined in console.log. Why? How to correct it and, I have to do it on this why only.

This is code for demofile:

```
exports.selectorquery = function() {
    var conn = "New connection";
    var nt = "Last Connect";

    function myFunc(arg) {
        return conn;    
    }

    setTimeout(myFunc, 3500, 'funky');
}
```

This is for run.js:

```
var go = require('./demofile.js');
console.log(go.selectorquery());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOur function is not returning anything:

Here's how you can do it.

**demofile.js**

```
exports.selectorquery = function (callback) {
    var conn = "New connection";
    var nt = "Last Connect";
    function myFunc(arg) {
        callback(null, conn);

    }
    setTimeout(myFunc, 3500, 'funky');
}
```

**run.js**

```
const go = require('./demofile');

go.selectorquery(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Now run:

```
node run.js
```

It should log

```
New connection
```

Read more: [NodeJS Export and Import Modules](https://www.journaldev.com/7599/nodejs-export-and-import-modules)

Hope it solved your query.

Answer (score 0):

Your `selectorquery` function does not return anything. Therefore, **undefined** is returned.

The function `myFunc` is scheduled for execution later but your console log will log the result of `selectorquery`, which is **undefined**.

Adding a console log to `myFunc` will log after the specified timeout:

```
function myFunc(arg) {
  console.log(conn);
  return conn;
}
```